# Optional parameter defaults

Tags: elisp

Emacs Lisp does not have syntactical support for non-nil defaults of optional parameters. What is the recommended idiom for supplying these parameters?

To clarify my point, here is one overly explicit way of doing so.

```el
(defun command (a &optional supplied-b)
  (let ((b (or supplied-b default-b)))
    (command-body a b)))
```

What, if anything, is the recommended style?

Answer (score 37):

Unless you use Common Lisp extensions as suggested by @legoscia, you need to check if the optional argument was specified. Note that you don't really need to use `let` here. This seems more idiomatic to me:

```
(defun command (a &optional b)
  (or b (setq b default))
  (command-body a b))
```

As suggested in the comments, using `unless` may be preferable to `or`:

```
(defun command (a &optional b)
  (unless b (setq b default))
  (command-body a b))
```

Also from the comments: the more pure functional style would be to use `let`, as in the original question, but you don't need separate variable names:

```
(defun my-command (a &optional b)
  (let ((b (or b default)))
    (command-body a b)))
```

Of course, if the optional parameter is only needed once you should just do this:

```
(defun my-command (a &optional b)
    (command-body a (or b default)))
```

Comment: -1: I don't think that it's good style to use a side-effecting expression like `setq` in a “pure” boolean form like `or`.  In my opinion `when` is definitely more appropriate here, but generally `let` is the expression of choice to establish or change local bindings.  IOW, the original code looks much nicer to me.

Comment: I agree that something like `(unless b (setq b default)` might be better. Personally, I think `let` is redundant here because `b` is already local to the `defun`.

Comment: It's a matter of taste, but I prefer pure code and pure bindings, i.e. `let` over a side-effecting form like `setq`.  It's code for a parameter default, but liberal use of `setq` to change local variables makes code hard to read and to follow.  I think it's best to consider all local bindings immutable, and only establish new bindings with `let`.  IOW, prefer a functional style over an imperative one.

Comment: this also doesnt allow for the optional being pass in as nil

Answer (score 31):

You can use `cl-defun`, which lets you specify a default value for optional arguments:

```
(cl-defun command (a &optional (b default-b))
  (command-body a b))
```

The default value, in this case `default-b`, will be evaluated every time the function is called.

Comment: dont forget to `(require 'cl-macs)`