# Idiomatic way to improve `insert-pair`

Tags: local-variables

I have the following custom implementation of `insert-pair`:

```el
(defun *-insert-pair (&optional arg open close)
  "Wrap next ARG sexps in parentheses.

If there is no next sexp, insert a new pair of parentheses."
  (interactive "p")
  (let ((arg (or arg 1))
        (exists-next-sexp t))
    (save-excursion
      (condition-case nil
          (forward-sexp)
        (scan-error (setq exists-next-sexp nil))))
    (if exists-next-sexp
        (insert-pair arg open close)
      (insert-pair nil open close))))
```

However, I don't like the use of the boolean var `exist-next-sexp`. Is there a more idiomatic way to write this so I can get rid of it?

Comment: 1. The last bit could be written as just `(insert-pair (and exists-next-sexp arg) open close)`, which makes clear that `insert-pair` is used in any case. 2. Don't bother with a second `ARG` variable (confusing to use the same name, and nothing gained). Just `(setq arg (or arg 1)`.

Comment: 3. Replace `(setq exists-next-sexp nil)` with `(setq arg nil)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of `let` vs `setq` for optional argument defaults is subjective, see https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/14203/780 for some discussion in the comments.

If you don't mind using setq here, you can combine the comments from @Drew and @npostavs for something fairly concise:

```
(defun *-insert-pair (&optional arg open close)
  (interactive "p")
  (setq arg (or arg 1))
  (save-excursion
    (condition-case nil
        (forward-sexp)
      (scan-error (setq arg nil))))
  (insert-pair arg open close))
```

You can also use `let` and combine things in to a single argument like this:

```
(defun *-insert-pair (&optional arg open close)
  (interactive "p")
  (let ((arg (save-excursion
               (condition-case nil
                   (progn
                     (forward-sexp)
                     (or arg 1))
                 (scan-error nil)))))

    (insert-pair arg open close)))
```