# How to make optional parameters default to true?

Tags: conditionals, default

In the question [Optional parameter defaults](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/14199), the suggested way to set default value for the parameter of an elisp function is along the lines of:

```
(defun my-command (a &optional b)
    (command-body a (or b default)))
```

Here, the optional parameter `b`of `my-command` is replaced by `(or b default)`.

I had a hard time trying to use this method to default `b` to true. I used `(or b t)`. But this value will be always a true, regardless of whether `b` is `nil` (the logical false) or not.

*How can one default the elisp optional parameter to true?*

-- Edit --

To clarify the question: `What does it even mean to you, to default to t?`

I am trying to write a function that runs only when a per-condition is met. This per-condition is represented as an optional parameter like `b` here that defaults to true.

The problem seems to be that `nil` is used both as the logical false and as "absence of value".

Comment: I think you are confusing yourself: `(or b t)` will evaluate to the value of `b` if it is not `nil` and it will evaluate to `t` if it the value of `b` is `nil`. Isn't that exactly what you want? Try `(let ((b nil)) (or b t))` and `(let ((b '(a b c))) (or b t))`.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: @NickD Thanks. Just fixed the typo.

Comment: So the problem is that if the optional parameter is absent, it is interpreted within the function as nil, which is indistinguishable from the parameter being present with value `nil` - but you would like to treat these two cases differently: in the first case, you would like to interpret it as being `t`  - yes?

Answer (score 1):

What does it even mean to you, to default to `t`? Defaulting for a parameter means that if the parameter isn't present explicitly (it's absent) then it gets the default value.

For Lisp parameters, absence is the same presence as `nil` - that's just the way it is. You (your code) can't distinguish the presence of a `nil` value from the absence of any value.

So if you write `(or nil t)` then whether the parameter is present as `nil` or is absent, the value you get will be `t`. Is that the behavior you want?

This has the scent of an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/231821). What is it that you're really trying to do?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have added the motivation why I needed a default-true parameter.

Comment: What you really want - still isn't clear. You say you want a *command*, but you're defining a *non*-command, a noninteractive function. I'm guessing maybe you want some defaulting to `t` interactively but not when the function is called from Lisp? If so, you can do that with an `interactive` form. But you'd have to say more about how the arguments (e.g. `a`) would be provided interactively (e.g., prompted for?). Overall, the question seems unclear or misguided. You'll likely get a helpful answer from someone if you figure out how to specify your (real) question clearly. That's my guess.

Comment: For completeness, I wanted to write a load function that loads a user .el file only when a pre-condition holds, which is the `b` here. But the more general question is language-wise: how to default to true. Hence the question here.

Answer (score 0):

If my interpretation of your question is correct:

> So the problem is that if the optional parameter is absent, it is interpreted within the function as `nil`, which is indistinguishable from the parameter being present with value `nil` - but you would like to treat these two cases differently: in the first case, you would like to interpret it as being `t` - yes?

the answer is: you cannot do that. See [Features of Argument Lists](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Argument-List.html) in the Emacs Lisp reference manual, where it states:

> If actual arguments for the optional and rest variables are omitted,
> then they always default to ‘nil’.  There is no way for the function to
> distinguish between an explicit argument of ‘nil’ and an omitted
> argument.  However, the body of the function is free to consider ‘nil’
> an abbreviation for some other meaningful value.  This is what
> ‘substring’ does; ‘nil’ as the third argument to ‘substring’ means to
> use the length of the string supplied.
>
> ```
> Common Lisp note: Common Lisp allows the function to specify what
> default value to use when an optional argument is omitted; Emacs
> Lisp always uses ‘nil’.  Emacs Lisp does not support ‘supplied-p’
> variables that tell you whether an argument was explicitly passed.
> ```